# Bypass Login for Magento Wishlist

Tags: magento

I'm wanting to use the power of the wishlist functionality to send emails to the site owner so that the site owner can initiative a call to talk over the service etc etc.

I want to only use the functionality of the wishlist and nothing else, so don't need the address book and the dashboard etc, but is there a way to bypass the login to the account section?

Chris

Comment: As far as I understand, you want to see your customer wishlists to be able to make an offer them. Or, what you want do with wishlist?

Comment: Its to allow them to use the functionality of the wishlist without creating an account.

Comment: To store whishlist we would need atleast any unique information for the user like email id to store its corresponding wishlist items. This is a broad question though.

Comment: I also have same problem, page should not be redirect to login when click on wishlist button.